# Searching for a certain local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, socle

> I am searching for a local ring $R$ such that $R/\mathrm{Soc}(R_R)$ is not isomorphic to the two-element ring $\mathbb Z_2$.

Here, by $\mathrm{Soc}(R_R)$ I mean the socle of the right $R$-module $R$.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take $K$ to be any field other than $\mathbb{Z}_2$, then the ring $R=K[X]/(X^2)$ satisfies your requirements, since it is local and $R/\mathrm{Soc}(R_R) \cong K$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that the only maximal ideal of $R$ is $(X)/(X^2)$, but what is its socle? And Why? Thanks!

Comment: @karparvar The ideal you mention is also the only non-trivial proper ideal of $R$.  Hence it is simple as an $R$-module, and since the socle of $R_R$ is the sum of all its simple submodules, you get that $(X)/(X^2)$ is the socle.

Answer (score 2):

For $p$ a prime and $n>2$, the only minimal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is $p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ and the quotient ring modulo the socle is $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z}$: it is a *uniserial* ring, that is, its ideals are linearly ordered.

For $p\ne2$ the example $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ is even simpler, because the socle is the same as the maximal ideal.